# How to get the dSYM file from the ipa file available on App Store

Tags: ios, ipa, dsym

There is a way to get a dSYM file from the ipa file that is available in App Store?

I've lost my archives that had that dSYM particularly.

Can I do that? I need the dSYM to upload to Crittercism.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Assuming you still have access to the app in iTunes Connect, it's now possible to download the dSYM from iTunes Connect, too. Login, go to My Apps, select your app, then tap on the Activity tab at the top. Tap on the relevant build, and, assuming the app was submitted with symbols in the first place, you should see the option to "Download dSYM."

The file you get is called dSYMs (without an extension) but it is in fact a zip file. Add the .zip extension, unzip, and you'll find your dSYM(s) inside.

(I needed to do this this week since Crashlytics was complaining about a missing dSYM: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35374388/2397068.)

Comment: Not be able to see where to download dSYM file on appstore.

Answer (score 16):

Unfortunately, the dSYM is included within the app archive but not within the `.ipa` file, so it is not possible to get it from downloading the app from the App Store.

This is for security reasons too- having the dSYM within the `.ipa` file would mean anyone could download it, potentially making it easier to hack/crack/reverse engineer your app.

Comment: If you need a dSYM for your own app, go to Window > Organizer in Xcode. Select the archive file for the appropriate app and build and tap "Download dSYMs...". See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34077722/crashlytics-were-missing-a-dsym-to-process-crashes.

Comment: @LaneRettig OP notes "I've lost my archives," so this wouldn't work for him.

Comment: Good call! Thanks for pointing it out. Just posted a more comprehensive answer (this was probably not possible previously!).

Comment: I am able to download DSYM files from AppStore as suggested by @LaneRettig.

Comment: My build was enterprise and it was not uploaded to TestFlight...somehow I lost my archives :(

Comment: Thanks @LaneRettig! In the meantime the button in the Organizer is called "Download Debug Symbols".